# Creating an interactive table for Android

Tags: android, interactive, timetable

I am currently trying to create a timetable based app. The table should be a grid of buttons and on touching each button. Each cell will have subject name,professor name, credits associated with it(I was hoping on touching one button it opens a prompt where I can enter these details)Any leads on how I should start to create this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should go for TableLayout or even LinearLayout. It depends on how complex your layout is.

You can simply place buttons and for button click events you can fire up another UI. You need to practice some Android dev I guess. Go ahead and learn more about Intents and basics of Android dev.

Good luck and welcome to the Android DevCommunity.